# Javascript (UJS) error using webpacker in rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have a very basic rails 6 app created with a single controller and index view, which looks like:

```
$ cat app/views/welcome/index.html.erb 
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hide_link' %>

<%= link_to "back here", root_url %>
  <br \>
<%= link_to "Should Disappear", root_path, id: 'be_gone', remote: true %>
```

The javascript being included in hide_link looks like:

```
$ cat app/javascript/packs/hide_link.js 
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
//window.onload = () => {
    let link = document.getElementById('be_gone');

    if (link) {
        link.onclick = () => link.style.display = "none";
    }

    console.log("In hide_link"); // just here to let me know it is running
} , false);
```

After starting the server the page accurately displays the 2 links and I have the Developer Tools
open on the Console page so as to see my message "In hide_link".
It also shows the following information:

```
hide_link.js:10
```

This appears on the far right of the Console.
Clicking the link "Should Disappear", does in fact disappear when clicked, but, when I click
the "back here" link the page is refreshed and the following change is made in the Console window:

```
hide_link.js:10

#replaced by

VM58 hide_link-8e7e6…20e4f0e3eed3.js:107
```

Now the VM58 and the random characters after hide_link- change each time I retry the process,
but the issue is that from this point on, although I can once again see the "Should Disappear" link, once clicked on it will no longer disappear until I refresh the entire page!!

So my question is, has anyone else come across this issue and hence a resolution?

Also, is it an issue with rails 6, webpacker or javascript or a combination of one or all?

Please let me know if any additional information can be provided to help in a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution can be found on the following page:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events

And the gist is to change the following:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

# to

window.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
```

All my javascripts are working even after being redirected back to the same page using a link